# jQueryUi Tabs isn't working when I use dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm currently working on a dealer search for my company. I want to add some tabs, so that the cutomers can filter the dealers per state. This means that the divs for the states are created dynamically, because the information comes from a CSV file.

I add the information like this:

```
function erzeugenTab()   {
     var $tabsDiv = $("#mapstabs");
      var linkList ='';
      var divRegion ='';
      var linkZahl = 1
    for (var i = 0; i < unique.length - 1; i++) {
    linkList = linkList + "<li><a href=\"#tabs"+linkZahl+"\">" + unique[i] + "</a></li>" ;
         divRegion = divRegion + "<div id =\"tabs"+linkZahl+"\">Test123</div>";
         linkZahl = linkZahl + 1;   
          }
      linkList = linkList + "</ul>";
      $tabsDiv.append(linkList);
      $tabsDiv.append(divRegion);
      $(function() {

        $('#mapstabs').tabs();

        });
}
```

However, no tabs are apearring. You can se it [here](http://www.testo.co.kr/kr/home/service/dealer_search/dealersearch2.jsp#tabs9).

Any idea what I"m missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try removing the $ on $tabsDiv turning it into just var tabsDiv?
Also, I do not see an open ul tag

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by removing function()?

```
 $(function() {

        $('#mapstabs').tabs();

        });
```

to

```
$('#mapstabs').tabs();
```